# self.manager.current only works in def on_enter(self):

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

I want to go to the next screen after finishing a time consuming calculation. Therefore, I wnat to define at the end of a function the screen that has to be shown. However, when I try the following:

```
    def gotoscreen1(self):
        print  self.manager (prints None)
        self.manager.current = 'screen2'
```

I have the error = AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'current'

When I try:

```
    def on_enter(self):
        print self.manager (prints <__main__.ScreenManagement object at 0x1227C688>)
        self.manager.current = 'screen2'
```

I can jump imediatly to screen 2, but that is not what I want ...
Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: you must provide a [mcve] of your problem, this can be caused by multiple reasons. for example where you have defined gotoscreen1 or when you call it.

Answer (score -1):

After a hort night sleep (thank you son) I woke up and knew the solution: I needed to pass the correct arguments when calling the function in the clock schedule

```
    Clock.schedule_interval(partial(self.gotoscreen1, self), 0.5)
```

Comment: Change `Clock.schedule_interval(partial(self.gotoscreen1, self), 0.5)` to `Clock.schedule_interval(self.gotoscreen1, 0.5)`